# Display of million records in JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a site where I have to fetch a million records from a database and show it in JqGrid. But when I do that it takes around 45 to 60 minutes to fetch and show the records.

I am using JqGrid with JSP, Hibernate, JPA and MySQL database.

Can anyone tell me how to go about this? So that time delay is reduced and records are loaded faster.

Thanks in advance

@UPDATE

I tried using JSON instead of XML and the time was reduced to 30 minutes. In this 30 minutes it is taking 16 minutes to fetch the data from the database and remaining 14 minutes to pass the data to frontend

@UPDATE 2

There are few ways by which I was able to decrease the time taken to load the data into jqgrid.

Way 1: I had ORDER BY clause in my query I removed that and the time was reduced from 45-60 minutes to 5 minutes

Way 2: Remove / reduce number of joins in the query.

Way 3: Instead of using the Hibernate or JPA object directly get the query result in result set and use that result set to create the json object.

By using 1 and 3 ways I have reduced my time to load a 200000 records to 1 min 32 secs.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't need to show millions of records at the same time. That would be an insane thing to do and completely impractical. What you need is to implement pagination. Server side pagination. So that you fetch only the records you can currently show on the screen. 10-30 records at a time seems like a reasonable amount to show. It is important that you perform the pagination at the database level to avoid fetching millions of records and display only very few of them.

Comment: I agree with this.  But I wanted to add...45 to 60 minutes?!?  That sounds crazy.  I'd try to determine, how much of this is time waiting on the database, how much waiting for download, how much parsing.  If your database is taking up a good chunk of that time, you might need to optimize it.

Comment: @dnuttle, what would take most time IMHO is transferring this sheer amount of data over the HTTP protocol to the client and most importantly building the DOM tree with so many elements inside the browser.

Comment: Probably.  It is definitely impractical to present a million rows to any user who is not a robot.

Comment: And if you do want to display 'all' rows you can fake the user by setting the rownum to 100 and scroll attribute to 1 in your jqGrid settings. This will look like all rows are loaded but when the user scrolls down 100 rows are automaticly loaded each time.